# error al instalar React

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babel

estoy intentando instalar React para empezar a estudiar y trastear con esta librería paro me da error.

Estoy siguiendo los siguientes pasos:

- `npm install -g create-react-app`
- `create-react-app mi-proyecto`
- `cd mi-proyecto`

pero al hacer `npm start` me da error al arrancar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error y así poder instalar correctamente React? No sé si también es obligatorio instalar webpack o Babel para que funcione.

Gracias

PD: He estado viendo e intentando hacer algunas de las soluciones que he visto por aquí, pero no me han funcionado y me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que existe una carpeta `node_modules` como ancestro de este proyecto (y cualquier otro que vayas a crear).

Esto posiblemente haya ocurrido porque alguna vez corriste `npm install` (por error) fuera de el directorio de una aplicación y los scripts generaron una carpeta `node_modules` como consecuencia.

Para solucionarlo, borra la carpeta `C:\Users\Derek\node_modules` y el `package.json` (si es que existe). Ahora, puedes utilizar:

```
npx create-react-app mi-super-app
```

Luego:

```
cd mi-super-app
npm start
```

Si ya habias creado la apliación, simplemente volvé a ejecutar `npm start`.

Ahora debería funcionar sin problemas.

- info sobre `create-react-app` [aquí](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started)
- info sobre `npx` [aquí](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner)

Comment: la versión de node que tengo es la v12.16.3, que creo que es la última, he ejecutado el `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` para desinstalarlo y después he ejecutado el `npx create-react-app mi-super-app` y me ha generado el proyecto y no sé si tengo que hacer algo más porque al ejecutar el npm start (dentro de la parpeta del proyecto), me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Según recuerdo una vez me sucedió algo similar. Dentro del directorio `Derek` tenes una carpeta `node_modules`. Esta se generó cuando corriste `npm install` dentro de ese directorio. Para solucionarlo, elimina la carpeta `C:\Users\Derek\node_modules`

Comment: Sí, fue eso, eliminé la carpeta `node-modules` y ejecuté el `npm start` y ya me arrancó, gracias

Comment: efectivamente la carpeta estaba en la ruta c:\Users\Usuario\node-modules, la elimine y el package.json